# Counting Duplicates and Grouping in an Arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist

for my project we have to manipulate certain LISP phrasing using Java. One of the tasks is given:

```
'(A A A A B C C A A D E E E E)
```

Group the duplicates and make the output like:

```
′((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E))
```

Notice how the first four A's are kept separate from the last 2...

My issues is with keeping track of how many is each letter. I added the given letters into an array list and I manipulated it a little:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        String val=list.get(i);
        String first=list.get(0);
        while (val.equals(first))
        {
            total+=1;
            val="X";
        }
    }
```

Total should be the number of times of the first occurrence but it keeps giving me 6. 6 is the correct number for all the A's in the sequence, but how do I get it to stop at the first four, record the number and move on the the next letter?

Comment: Because you are using `==`. To compare String values, you need to use `equals`, such as `val.equals(first)`.

Comment: How is the list of letters provided? A single String?

Comment: The logic would follow: Get the first letter and start a counter at 1. Check the next letter to see if it is the same. If it is, increment the counter and check the next one. Repeat until a different letter is found. Once found, print the counter + previous letter, reset the counter to 1 and repeat for the next letter

Answer (score 1):

Here is with Java 8 Stream API.

```
 Map<Character, Long> countedDup =  Arrays.asList('A' ,'A' ,'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E')
        .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
            System.out.println(countedDup);//{A=6, B=1, C=2, D=1, E=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String first = list.get(i);
        int total = 1;
        while (i + 1 < list.size() && first.equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
            total++;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("(" + total + first + ")");
    }
```

You can debug to know how it run.

***** Note that when compare 2 String objects, never use `==`. Use method `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the required output that you specified in your question, I would keep track of the current and next values in the given list. The element count starts at 1 and is incremented when the equality condition is true, otherwise it is reset to 1. And the final output is only updated when the equality condition is false.

Sample code:

**EDIT** I updated my code based on @Ascalonian's suggestion.

```
String inputString = "'(A A A A B C C A A D E E E E)";

// I assume that the input always starts with "'("
String finalOutput = inputString.substring(0, 2);
int valCount = 1;

String valCurrent = inputString.substring(2, 3);
String valNext = "";

for (int i = 4; i < inputString.length(); i++) {

    valNext = inputString.substring(i, i + 1);
    if (valNext.equals(" ")) {
        continue;
    }

    if (valCurrent.equals(valNext)) {
        valCount++;
    } else {
        finalOutput += "(" + valCount + valCurrent + ")";
        valCount = 1;
    }
    valCurrent = valNext;
}

finalOutput += ")";

System.out.println(finalOutput);
```

> Output string: '((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E))

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't actually read your comment :). I just wanted to solve it because I thought it was interesting.

Comment: Actually, just noticed this does not consider the spaces and the single quote

Comment: I actually made the assumption that there were no spaces and I didn't notice the single quote. I'll update my answer later. However the OP did not specify the expected behaviour for single quotes. For example, what happens when a single quote is in the middle of the string? I can only make assumptions in this case.

Comment: @Ascalonian Thanks for pointing out what I didn't notice. I updated my answer.

Comment: Your output is missing the (4E)

Comment: Lol...I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70239/discussion-between-ascalonian-and-iruth).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, though didn't used arrayList:

**Edited:** as per pointed out by **Ascalonian**

```
String text = "'(A A V A B C C X X X X A A Z Z Z K L N N N N N)";
int counter = 1;
System.out.print("'(");
for (int i = 2; i < text.length() - 1; i = i + 2) {
    System.out.print("(");
    while (((i + 2) < text.length())
        && (text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i + 2))) {
    ++counter;
    i += 2;
    }
    System.out.print(counter + "" + text.charAt(i) + ")");
    counter = 1;
}
System.out.print(")");
```

o/p will be for sample text:

> ((2A)(1V)(1A)(1B)(2C)(4X)(2A)(3Z)(1K)(1L)(5N))

Comment: Your `text` does not match the example String provided. It has spaces and a single quote

Comment: @Ascalonian thanks for pointing it out. Didn't saw that. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if using an `ArrayList` is a requirement, but if not, I use a different approach where I get just the letters, strip away the white spaces, make it a `char[]` and iterate each letter.

```
// the initial LISP phrase
String lispPhrase = "'(A A A A B C C A A D E E E E)";

// Pull out just the letters
String letters = lispPhrase.substring(2, lispPhrase.length()-1);

// Remove the white space between them
letters = letters.replaceAll("\\s","");

// Get an array for each letter
char[] letterArray = letters.toCharArray();

char previousLetter = ' ';
char nextLetter = ' ';
int letterCounter = 1;

System.out.print("'(");

// now go through each letter
for (char currentLetter : letterArray) {
    // If the first time through, set previousLetter
    if (previousLetter == ' ') {
        previousLetter = currentLetter;
    }else {
        nextLetter = currentLetter;

        // Is the next letter the same as before?
        if (previousLetter == nextLetter) {
            letterCounter++;
        }else {
            // If the next letter is different, print out the previous letter and count
            System.out.print("(" + letterCounter + previousLetter + ")");

            // Reset the counter back to 1
            letterCounter = 1;
        }

        previousLetter = nextLetter;
    }
}

System.out.print("(" + letterCounter + previousLetter + "))");
```

This gives the output of:

> '((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E))